# Add multiple values into single row MYSQL / PHP and separate

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to create a system where registered user can join a 'trip'. Once he submitted that he want to join, his user id will be captured and send to the database in a column called usersJoined. The idea is that multiple users can join the 'trip', and all the id's are stored within one cell and separated with a comma. To retrieve the id's later, I will use the explode function.

My problem is, that the last appended id also has a comma. The explode function will see the whitespace after the last comma as an 'object?' and it will be stored within the array that captured the explode function.

Is there a way I can make sure the last appended id does not have a comma?
Or do you have suggestions for another method?

Here's my code:

```
function joinPost($id, $s_email){

    // Captures the user ID from a SESSION variable received outside this function
    $query = "SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '$s_email'";
    $result = $this->db->query($query);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {        
        while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
            $userID = $row['id'];
        }
    }
    $userIDwithComma = $userID . ','; // <-- this should be different, I guess 

    // Check if user joined already
    $query = "SELECT `usersJoined` FROM `trips` WHERE id = '$id'";
    $result = $this->db->query($query);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {      
            $usersJoined = $row['usersJoined'];
        }
    }

    $users = explode(',', $usersJoined);
    $check = 0;

    foreach($users as $user){
        if($user == $userID){
            $check = 1;
        }
    }

    if($check != 1){
        $sql = "UPDATE trips SET usersJoined = CONCAT(usersJoined, ?) WHERE id = '$id'";

        if($stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql)) {
            $stmt->bind_param('s', $userIDwithComma);
            $stmt->execute();

            if($stmt->fetch()) {
                $stmt->close();
                return true;
            }
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        header('Location: trips.php?status=already_joined');
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just have a separate table and handle the query with a join?

Comment: @RowlandShaw what do you mean exactly?

Comment: Just store the data in a properly normalized design.

Comment: I mean something along the lines of what @barbarity has proposed as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh my... You designed the Database badly. You should create a many-to-many relationship. Right now, you have two tables: `Users` and `Trips`. You should create a new table with FK `user_id` and `trip_id` like this:

```
UsersGoTrip
=====================
| user_id | trip_id | 
=====================
|       1 |       1 |
|       2 |       1 |
|       1 |       2 |
=====================
```

Then, adding, removing and selecting users that go for a specific trip or trips that a specific user is attending is just one query away.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the comment. I'm a beginning PHP programmer so any advice is appreciated :) I will try to Google more about this approach. Thank you

Comment: We are here to help. Once you read about it, you will ask yourself how could you have done it any other way. I promise. If you found this answer helpful, please upvote it and mark it as correct so others with your problem find the answer easier.

Answer (score 0):

```
$users = explode(',', rtrim($usersJoined, ',')); // trim commas from right
```

or

```
$users = array_filter(explode(',', $usersJoined)); // remove from array if empty value
```

Answer (score 0):

You must eliminate the last comma,

Change this:

```
$stmt->bind_param('s', $userIDwithComma);
```

to:

```
$stmt->bind_param('s', substr($userIDwithComma, 0, -1));
```